# Excel: how to count unique ID within each state as well as the tickets purchased within each state

Tags: excel, database

I'm completely new to the excel world, and I am currently working on this very specific problem. Assume I'm doing statistics for a ticketing platform. Here is the data I was given:

- **Account ID**: a unique ID for each user
- **State**: the mailing state for the account (each account will only have one mailing state)
- **Order Qty**: amount of tickets purchased

| Account ID | State | Order Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | TX | 4 |
| 101 | TX | 6 |
| 102 | NY | 5 |
| 103 | TX | 7 |
| 103 | TX | 9 |
| 104 | CA | 1 |

I would like to create a table that dynamically count the unique IDs by state, as well as the total number of tickets bought for each state. The table will look something like this:

| State | Unique ID | Order Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TX | 2 | 26 |
| NY | 1 | 5 |
| CA | 1 | 1 |

I tried to merge the state column but that does not calculate the unique ID and Order Qty for the state.

**Update**:
I tried using group and subtotal and it gave me a very close solution following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFdhANcS6VA

But there is one thing missing, which is the Account ID unique count, because it seems like Excel does not have a built in Count(unique) like apple numbers does:
[image]

Is there a way to apply the Unique count subtotal to each State group in excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unique count use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7))*($B$2:$B$7=F2))
```

or if you have O365

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7=F2,"")))
```

for quantity:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$7,F2,$C$2:$C$7)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF` for unique IDs and `SUMIF` for quantities.

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"TX")`

`=SUMIF(B:B,"TX",C:C)`